# 404(not found) error in my console

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am trying to do pagination using ajax but when ever I click on next page it gives me this error in my console

```
 jquery-2.2.3.min.js:4 GET http://localhost:8000/patientPanel/ajax/patientHospital?page=2 404 (Not Found)
```

I defined my route too but still having this error.Sharing my code of route, controller and view below.

Controller

```
public function index()
{
    $hospitals = Hospital::paginate(3);
    return View::make('patientPanel/patientHospital')
        ->with('hospitals',$hospitals);
}
```

Route

```
  Route::get('/patientPanel/patientHospital', 'patientHospitalController@index');

  Route::get('ajax/patienthospital', function(){

      $hospitals = Hospital::paginate(3);

      return View::make('/patientPanel/patientHospital')
          ->with('hospitals',$hospitals)->render();
  });
```

View

```
<section id="team">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    @foreach($hospitals as $hospital)
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 wow fadeIn content" data-
       wow-offset="50" data-wow-delay="1.3s">
      <div class="team-wrapper">
        <img src="/uploads/{{$hospital->picture }}" class="img-responsive" alt="team img 1" style="height: 270px; width: 500px">
          <div class="team-des">
            <h4>{{$hospital->name}}</h4>
            <span>Designer</span>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elitquisque tempus ac eget diam et laoreet phasellus ut nisi id leo molest.</p>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
  </div>
  {{$hospitals->links()}}
  </div>
 </section>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).on('click','.pagination a',function(e){

 e.preventDefault();
 var page = ($(this).attr('href').split('page='))[1];
 getProducts(page);
 });

 function getProducts(page)
 {
$.ajax({
   url:'/ajax/products?page='+page
}).done(function(data){

    $('.content').html(data);
    location.hash = page;
  });

 }
```

Please tell me why I am getting this error as I have defined route too.

Comment: Where you are returning paginated products? You're returning view in both routes.

Comment: You are doing get request from ajax and in route `'ajax/patienthospital` where is the page_id parameter?

Comment: from your ajax you are calling `/ajax/products?page=` and in your route you are defined route for `ajax/patienthospital` i mean what is this?

Answer (score 0):

You set route as `ajax/patienthospital` and calling as `/patientPanel/ajax/patientHospital`

Either change url from

```
ajax/patienthospital
```

to

```
/patientPanel/ajax/patientHospital
```

Or

Add `ajax` in route

```
Route::get('/patientPanel/ajax/patientHospital',
```

**Update**

I think its just `/` issue ,use with `/`

```
/ajax/patienthospital
```

Instead just

```
ajax/patienthospital
```